# Batch file won't delete contents of a folder

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a program that will delete some files and perfrom rutine maintance on a computer by just clickin on one file. I'm testing it as I'm going along and realized that it's not deleting the folders. I want to delete everything within the folders but not the folders themselves. Here is my code so far:

```
@echo off
title SYSTEM Optimiation

echo Deleting Temp Folder
del /q /f "C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\TEMP"

echo.

echo DONE

echo.

echo Deleting Download folder
del /q /f "C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\My Documents\Downloads"
echo.
echo DONE
echo.
echo.
echo Hit any key to exit.
pause >nul
```

Comment: You you don't want the folders to be deleted and they are not deleted, where exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Joey I want the contents of them to be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using wildcards and the `/s` switch on `del`:

```
del /q /s /f "%userprofile%\My Documents\Downloads\*"
```

but this will probably leave directories inside intact, but empty. Another option would be the quite explicit:

```
for /d /r "%userprofile%\My Documents\Downloads" %%x in (*) do rd /s /q "%%x"
for /r "%userprofile%\My Documents\Downloads" %%x in (*) do del /f "%%x"
```

Comment: I'll try that hover what is %userprofile%? Is that the same as %username%?

Comment: No, it's not named the same as `%username%`, why would it be the same? It's the path to the current user's profile. Similarly you can use just `%temp%` for the other directory ...

Comment: I tried <code> del /q /s /f "%userprofile%\My Documents\Downloads\*" <code> and that didn't work. I'll try the other method you showed.

Comment: The `for /d /r "%userprofile%\My Documents\Downloads" %%x in (*) do rd /s /q "%%x"
for /r "%userprofile%\My Documents\Downloads" %%x in (*) do del /f "%%x"` worked to do what I wanted however I don't understand it all. Good thing for the `/?` that I can use.

Answer (score 1):

Here much simpler than above. Current directory will be locked and therefore will not be deleted with others.

```
cd %Temp% && rmdir /s /q .
```